# Can concurrent processes slow download performance in the case of a disk bottleneck?

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive

I am currently downloading a reasonably large amount of data using a 1Gbit connection and would anticipate a download speed of ~125MB/s (this has been achieved on the same connection on a different download).

The download speed is currently at ~65MB/s.

I am experimenting with using a simple Python script to run 15 download processes, on 15 of the 16 cores on the CPU, to try to resolve 1) potential (connection-based) server-side throttling, and 2) that there are many files and a small amount of processing involved (checksums, file verification etc.) and I want to keep the connection fully utilized where possible.

One factor that could be causing the bottleneck is the HDD write speed - it is a single external 12TB HDD (USB 3.1) 5400 RPM. Looking at the disk queue length in perfmon (Windows 10), it looks like the queue fluctuates around 30 (28-32).

Could I be right in my thinking that having multiple downloads of different files (and different directories) could be leading to slower overall speeds due to the disk writing in multiple places?

If the disk queue is too long (as in this case), would this lead to download throttling automatically? The protocol is SSL TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem and am now getting ~113MB/s speeds.

The drive was indeed the bottleneck and the problem was solved by enabling disk caching in Windows. This is disabled by default on external HDDs to enable quick removal.

For anyone who stumbles across this, you can enable disk caching by following these steps in Windows 10:

1. Go to Device Manager (Ctrl-X)
2. Expand the "Disk Drives" section
3. Right-click and select Properties on the relevant drive
4. Go to the 'Policies' tab
5. Select 'Better performance'
6. Click OK
7. Restart the computer